# An approximation question from "Nuclear Models" by Judah Eisenberg and Walter Greiner

Tags: nuclear-physics, approximations

I'm looking at page 311 of the book "Nuclear Theory" by Judah Eisenberg and Walter Greiner. Now for identity (49) which is: 
$$\omega_{1,2}^2=\frac{\omega_\alpha^2+\omega_\zeta^2-2bc\omega_\alpha\omega_\zeta}{2(1-b^2)}\pm \sqrt{1/4\bigg(\frac{\omega_\alpha^2+\omega_\zeta^2-2cb\omega_\alpha\omega_\zeta}{1-b^2}\bigg)^2-\omega^2_\alpha\omega_\zeta^2(1-c^2)/(1-b^2)}$$ they write that

> for $b,c\ll1$ and $\omega_\alpha<\omega_\zeta$, we get $\omega_1\approx \omega_\alpha, \omega_2\approx\omega_\zeta$.

How did they derive these two approximations? If I take $b\to 0,c\to 0$ i get for the plus sign $\omega^2_\alpha+\omega_\zeta^2$ i assume that because one frequency is smaller than the other it gets neglected, but for the minus sign I get zero. How to derive these two approximations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the limit $b,c\to 0$ the term under the radical becomes
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac14 ( \omega_\alpha^2 + \omega_\zeta^2 )^2 - \omega_\alpha^2 \omega_\zeta^2}
&= \frac12 \sqrt{\left(\omega_\alpha^4 + \omega_\zeta^4 + 2 \omega_\alpha^2 \omega_\zeta^2 \right) - 4\omega_\alpha^2 \omega_\zeta^2}
\\&=\frac12\sqrt{\left( \omega_\alpha^2 - \omega_\zeta^2 \right)^2 }
\\&=\frac12\left(\omega_\alpha^2 - \omega_\zeta^2 \right)
\end{align*}
So when you add or subtract the term outside the radical you get one or the other of your $\omega$; probably the only reason they are ordered $\omega_\alpha < \omega_\zeta$ is so that you can say which solution is the bigger one.

This sort of secret completing-the-square happens all the time; you eventually learn to look for it.